# Rails use object property in path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to get a path helper to work with a object's name property

so in routes

```
get 'reset/:name', to: 'users#reset_name', as: 'reset_name'
```

in controller reset_name def

```
... @user
```

in view (html.erb)

```
... <%= link_to reset_name_path(@user) %>
```

for some reason the link is still coming out like  /reset/name/1, which uses the object's id and not name. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the `to_param` method to make Rails use the `name` instead of the `id` when generating routes.  This will apply to all routes that operate on the `User` model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param
    name
  end
end
```

Alternatively, if you only want to do this for some routes, you can just change your `link_to`:

```
<%= link_to reset_name_path(:name => @user.name) %>
```